# How to transition from rough vocals to clean vocals?

Tags: technique, voice, practice, metal

I am a lead singer on a band, I spent a lot of time learning rough vocals, like in this example:

Now i want to learn clean vocals, there's some practical way to carry my previous learning to this new style?

Comment: I've never faced a similar situation, so I won't venture into a formal answer, but (assuming you normally don't "throat speak") I would suggest that you practice speaking (e.g. reciting poems) and work your vocal resonance and timber in that mode and then little by little (i.e. starting with very simple melodies) transition into singing mode. A lot of information in this stack and elsewhere (e.g. this question https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/46620/what-exactly-is-singing-with-your-head-voice/46635#46635) may help find a balanced vocal resonance.

Comment: This information can be really helpful, It's a really good starting point for improving general technique. I will que the question up for more specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

José directed me to you because we are having a complementary problem. I am the opposite of you, i'm trying to re-achieve unclean vocals/rough vocals as i used to be able to do, in the most healthy way possible. As I'm in a popular music course in university I have increased my knowledge on technique in clean singing. If you want, we could skype one day and could give you some tips of clean singing as it's easier to explain by speaking to the person directly and giving vocal examples than by written, I know it sounds weird but if it's a problem, I can try my best and explain by written here. But I must admit I do struggle to find sometimes the right way/ words to explain my point ! Have a nice day/evening

Comment: Thanks for taking up my challenge Lydia, however in alignment with the purpose of stack exchange it would be better if you shared some of your experience in writing here, both for the OP's benefit as well as the rest of the community. I'm afraid that, as it is, your answer may not be considered a good one, despite your good will.

Comment: +1 for the initiative,  I kinda want to wait if someone can bring an answer to be shared with the community (following the Stack Exchange alignment), but in the lack of anwers I would be very grateful for the opportunity :)

Comment: Great! Ok no worries! I will do it next week or whenever I have time, I'll share my personal experience!